# default arguments in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, default, arguments

Can I use default arguments in a constructor like this maybe

`Soldier(int entyID, int hlth = 100, int exp = 10, string nme) : entityID(entyID = globalID++), health(hlth), experience(exp), name(nme = SelectRandomName(exp))
{ }`

I want for example exp = 10 by default but be able to override this value if I supply it in the constructor otherwise it should use the default.

How can I do this, I know my approach does not work....

If I supply any value in the initialization list no matter whatever I supply in constructor gets overwritten ofcourse on the other hand whenever I supply a value in constructor then why do I need a default value in the first place as every time I am supplying a value for object initiation...?

Should I use different overloaded constructors or do you people have any other ideas....?

Comment: Yes, you should use overloaded constructors.

Comment: Your constructor definition will not compile, while your post seems to describe a run-time behavior. This means that most likely you posted a fake constructor definition. Please, post real one.

Comment: If there is a possibility that your constructor can be called with only one parameter, it ought to be `explicit`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Default arguments can only be supplied to a continuous range of parameters that extends to the end of the parameter list. Simply speaking, you can supply default arguments to 1, 2, 3, ... N *last* parameters of a function. You cannot supply default arguments to parameters in the middle of the parameter list, as you are trying to do above. Either rearrange your parameters (put `hlth` and `exp` at the end) or supply a default argument for `nme` as well.

Additionally, you constructor initializer list doesn't seem to make any sense. What was the point of passing `entyID` and `nme` from outside, if you override their values anyway in the constructor initializer list?

Answer (score 2):

All of the parameters with default arguments need to be after any required arguments. You should move the `nme` parameter before `hlth`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this, however, all your defaulted args would need to go at the end.  So, in your example, the constructor signature would be

```
Soldier(int entyID, string nme, int hlth = 100, int exp = 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arguments with default values must be the last arguments in the function declaration. In other words, there can not be any arguments without default values following one with a default value.

Answer (score 1):

Only trailing arguments can be default arguments. You would need to give `nme` a default argument or change the order of the arguments that the constructor takes so that `hlth` and `exp` come last.

As regards the assignment you make in the initialiser list what happens there is that the member `entityID` gets assigned the value that is returned by the assignment of `globalID++` to `entyID` which will be the value of `entyID` after the assignment. A similar thing happens for `name`.